# Order a queryset by ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models

Background: There is a competition. Each Team Has Three tries ('Runs'). The final score is the run with the highest score, and if scores are identical, the best time counts. I want to display the total ranking. Here is my code:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    #attributes

    def get_best_run(self):
       return self.run_set.order_by('-score', 'seconds')[0]

class Run(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey('Team')
    round_number = models.IntegerField('round')
    score = models.IntegerField('score')
    seconds = models.IntegerField('score')
```

now I want to sort teams by their best score. If given a specific team, I can `self.run_set.order_by('score', 'seconds')`, but how would I do that for *all* teams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. It's simple to use annotate to work out the max score for each time, and sort by that.

```
from django.db.models import Max
Team.objects.annotate(max_score=Max('run__score')).order_by('max_score')
```

This doesn't take into account the seconds value, though. I'm not sure if this will work:

```
Team.objects.annotate(max_score=Max('run__score')).annotate(max_seconds=Max('run__seconds')).order_by('max_score', 'max_seconds')
```

Comment: Since it got unedited: I tested it thoroughly, and the bottom solution works.